# How to use the five first values of my CSV file as x axis with matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My python scraper pulls dynamic values from the web and saves them as:
([year, month, day, hour, minute, price])

I would like to put the first 5 on the x axis and the price on the y. 
For example 2017/03/01/09:34 x coordinate and 1230 y coordinate. Or even better simply have the hour and minute as x coordinate and the year month and day as titles.

Here is the code I use to append the csv file:

```
import csv
with open("example.csv", 'a') as example:
        Writer = csv.writer(example)
        Writer.writerow([year, month, day, hour, minute, price])
```

I just started learning matplotlib yesterday but so far this is the code I tried for plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(example.csv")

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Submit an MWE  (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample data, so you can have a better shot at getting a helpful answer

Comment: i added the code i use to append and what i know for plotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to plot 5 values on the *x* axis, but conveniently, your row is just an exploded date and a price, so you can re-form it into a 2 column dataframe.

so, with a csv that looks like:

```
year,month,day,hour,minute,price
1999, 12,    31,  23,   59,   10
2000, 12,    20,  23,   59,   15
2001,  6,    15,  23,   59,   13
2001, 12,     2,  23,   59,   17
```

you can handle it like this:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./example.csv")


def make_a_real_date(the_row):
    year = the_row[0]
    month = the_row[1]
    day = the_row[2]
    hour = the_row[3]
    minute = the_row[4]
    price = the_row[5]  # although we don't care about price for now
    # https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)


df["real_datetime"] = df.apply(make_a_real_date, axis=1)

df = df.drop(["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute"], axis=1)

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

This will give you a graph of time and price. You might want to look into [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html) too. Plotting time series data is a pain!